# How to handle JavaScript objects (parsed JSON) that contain null?

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript/jQuery to fetch data as json via an ajax call. The json is then parsed to a JavaScript object. Let's call the object `var`.

Now I want to assign a value from the object to a variable:

```
let publicationDay = val["work-summary"][0]["publication-date"]["day"]["value"]
```

This works, as long this value exists. However, for some results, the object contains `null` not for `["value"]` but for `["day"]` (as shown below)

```
val["work-summary"][0]["publication-date"]["day"] // is null
```

In this case, `let publicationDay = val["work-summary"][0]["publication-date"]["day"]["value"]` will throw the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: val['work-summary'][0]['publication-date'].day is null
```

and the code execution is stopped. Sure, I can check whether `val["work-summary"][0]["publication-date"]["day"] === null`, but what would be the most elegant way to handle this case? Maybe, in the future even

```
val['work-summary'][0]['publication-date'] // is null
```

may occur and my check for `null` does not work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining may help.

Comment: The best way would probably be to use Typescript, and then you can use libraries like zod, that are designed for this use case.

Comment: Probably you can try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup for validation. It works with non-typescript code.

Comment: @Andy that's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying optional chaining.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Assuming that any of those values could be null:

```
let publicationDay = val?.["work-summary"]?.[0]?.["publication-date"]?.["day"]?.["value"]
```

It will set the variable to either `day.value` or `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Depends heavily on your context but here’s some examples.

```
const publicationDate = val['work-summary'][0]['publication-date'];

// usage
console.log(publicationDate && publicationDate.day && publicationDate.day.value); // very basic
console.log(publicationDate?.day?.value); // optional chaining, better if supported by your environment (should be)
console.log(get(publicationDate, “day.value”)); // lodash get()
```